# Delete from table when field does not match another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the following SELECT statement to craft a DELETE statement after I get it working.

Basically table "listing" has a bunch of record that need to be removed.  If the EmpNo cannot be found in address table then I want to remove the record from listing table.  I keep getting a invalid syntax.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM address A
LEFT JOIN listing B
USING (EmpNo)
WHERE B.EmpNo IS <> A.EmpNo
```

Comment: In the future, please post the error message. It is pretty easy to spot this time, but isn't always.  And MySQL 1064 errors typically point to exactly the place where the error occurs.

Comment: Okay, will do.  This one just gave a really generic error so I assumed I had really messed up the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `IS` keyword here:

```
WHERE B.EmpNo IS <> A.EmpNo
```

Should be:

```
WHERE B.EmpNo  <> A.EmpNo
```

If `EmpNo` exists with the same name in both tables, `USING` will work correctly there. Otherwise, you can be a little more explicit with `ON`:

```
FROM 
  address A
  LEFT JOIN listing B
    ON A.EmpNo = B.EmpNo
```

To find those records in `A` with no match in `B`, test for `B.EmpNo IS NULL` instead of `B.EmpNo <> A.EmpNo`.

```
WHERE B.EmpNo IS NULL
```

Comment: Hmmm..I am trying this and it is deleting all records in listing, even the ones where there is a match with address?

DELETE A.*
FROM address A
LEFT JOIN qemplisting B
ON B.EmpNo = A.EmpNo

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Sorry I missed this comment.  To delete only those not matching, you need `WHERE B.EmpNo IS NULL` - meaning there's a record in A which has no matching record in B.